# Ubuntu server 21.10 does not finish its first boot on my raspberry

Tags: ubuntu, boot, raspberry-pi

Maybe I'm asking a very noob question but I'm a bit desperate.
I'm trying to run Raspberry Pi zero W, with the following things connected:

- SD 8GB with Ubuntu server preinstalled (following the guide mentioned
  later on),
- the official keyboard (I thought it could be a problem of
  my other keyboard),
- the official power source connected (I thought also it could be a lack of power),
- the screen via micro HDMI,
- and the ethernet cable plugged to keyboard with a USB hub.

All plugged in before powering the Pi.

I've followed this guide:
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#4-boot-ubuntu-server
At the fourth step, I wait after de log-in prompt, it outputs some more lines after the log-in prompt, but after this the keyboard cursor stays tilting. But it does nothing and it doesn't respond to keyboard in any way.

The text after ubuntu login is the following:

```
[ 126.731034] cloud-init[2162]: Cloud-init v.21.3-1-g6803368d-Oubuntu3 running 'modules:final' at *-a date: Wed, etc.-*.
[ 127.431473] cloud-init[2162]: Cloud-init v.21.3-1-g6803368d-Oubuntu33 finished at *-a date again-*. Datasource DataSourceNoCloud [seed=/dev/mmcblk0p1] [dsmode=net]. Up 127.41 seconds.
```

What I'm missing? Is there any additional information I could provide you? I don't know what to do.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: One thing there happening is command `unminimize` issued. And it takes much time. Did you wait till it completes? Please share what is on the screen to tell what may be the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering pbies. I wait for the complete configuration of the boot, then "ubuntu login:" pop up, after a few seconds this is written:
[ 126.731034] cloud-init[2162]: Cloud-init v. 21.3-1-g6803368d-Oubuntu3 running 'modules:final' at *-a date: Wed, etc.-*. 
Another line with: [127.431473] cloud-init[2162]: Cloud-init v. 21.3-1-g6803368d-Oubuntu33 finished at *-a date again-*. Datasource DataSourceNoCloud [seed=/dev/mmcblk0p1] [dsmode=net]. Up 127.41 seconds.
The boot is completed in < 2 minutes. After, I've waited for +30min just in case, but nothing else happens.

Comment: Is the internet available for the Pi? The log indicating **cloud**-int might lead one to think it's looking for drivers from the web.

Comment: Thanks DrMoishe Pippik, is the same ethernet cable I use on my PC. Every device I have connected to that ethernet cable has worked on the spot. What would you suggest me to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to a computer technician and he gave the hint: it was a problem of drivers and recommended me to try more OS. I installed Raspberry Pi OS (64 bits, Desktop) and my second keyboard (Logitech K310) is recognized. So up and running after all this struggle!
Thank you very much for all your contributions that lead me to find the solution!

Answer (score 0):

After comments seems like there is not enough power given to keyboards attached via micro-USB, that's why they are not working.

Solution to that would be getting more powerful charger.

Comment: Hi pbies, thanks, the problem is that one exactly: at that point, I can't login in. It doesn't respond to anything I do with the keyboard. I tried with each restart a different thing: login, Ctrl+Alt+F2, Esc, Enter and other things I found on forums, but it doesn't react to any.

Comment: What happens when you press Num Lock? How the keyboard is connected? Tried another keyboard or this keyboard on other computer?

Comment: Nothing happens. I'm using the official raspberry keyboard, which works perfectly on my netbook. I tried two other keyboards, supported by raspberry according to the official webpage, but none of them responds, NumLock or any other button.

Comment: @Fernando so you have bad keyboards or you are not connecting them properly. How are the keyboards connected?

Comment: Let's see: all keyboards run perfectly in my netbook PC and my workstation. None of them respond at the raspberry. About their connection: the two classic keyboards connect with a male USB-micro USB connector to raspberry. The official raspberry keyboard I connected it in both ways, micro USB to keyboard and USB to raspberry (through the previous connector USB-microUSB) and viceversa (USB to keyboard and micro USB directly to rasp). Connect a keyboard is simple and they run properly in three different devices.

Comment: To validate raspberry ports I've connected a phone with the maleUSB-microUSB connector and it charges.

Comment: @Fernando in that case I can only suspect not enough current for keyboards connected via micro-USB. Can't tell more.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your dedication. That's the reason I bought the official charger, to ensure its 12.7W. I'm just plugging the keyboard and a screen with its own power. Damn. I'm going to study all the boot process in case it gives further hints. Thank you!

Comment: I've checked with a multimeter the USB hub from the offical keyboard outputs 5.2V while plugged with the raspberry booted. And also connecting the ethernet cable to the same HUB, gets light and tilts like runing.

Comment: @Fernando it's not about voltage, it's about current.

Comment: Since current is measured by voltage and amps, could you extend what do you mean? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Fernando seems like you are missing power to power the keyboards.